# Aligning mathml equations at equal sign

Tags: mathml

I have three equations in MathML. I want to align them at equals sign. I certainly can do this using mtable and columnalign. Is there much better and clean way to do this  ?

Answer (score 2):

`<maligngroup>` and its kin were never widely implemented and have not made it into [MathML Core](https://w3c.github.io/mathml-core/). I haven’t found any explicit statement on what’s supposed to be used instead; the [W3C MathML Polyfills repo](https://github.com/w3c/mathml-polyfills/wiki/MathML-Polyfill-Task-Force-Guidelines) doesn’t even try to replace them.

But I really don’t see anything in Core’s limited element set that would do the job *except* `<mtable>`. So that’s almost certainly the way to go.

Here’s a simple(?) example, together with how Firefox renders it on my system using the Latin Modern Math font.

```html
<math display="block">
    <mtable>
        <mtr>
            <mtd><mi>y</mi></mtd>
            <mtd><mo>=</mo></mtd>
            <mtd>
                <mfrac>
                    <mrow>
                        <msup><mi>x</mi><mn>2</mn></msup>
                        <mo>&minus;</mo>
                        <mn>4</mn>
                    </mrow>
                    <mrow>
                        <mi>x</mi><mo>&minus;</mo><mn>2</mn>
                    </mrow>
                </mfrac>
            </mtd>
            <mtd></mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
            <mtd></mtd>
            <mtd><mo>=</mo></mtd>
            <mtd>
                <mfrac>
                    <mrow>
                        <mrow>
                            <mo>(</mo>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn>
                            </mrow>
                            <mo>)</mo>
                        </mrow>
                        <mo>&InvisibleTimes;</mo>
                        <mrow>
                            <mo>(</mo>
                            <mrow>
                                <mi>x</mi><mo>&minus;</mo><mn>2</mn>
                            </mrow>
                            <mo>)</mo>
                        </mrow>
                    </mrow>
                    <mrow>
                        <mi>x</mi><mo>&minus;</mo><mn>2</mn>
                    </mrow>
                </mfrac>
            </mtd>
            <mtd></mtd>
        </mtr>
        <mtr>
            <mtd></mtd>
            <mtd><mo>=</mo></mtd>
            <mtd><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn></mtd>
            <mtd>
                <mtext>where&nbsp;</mtext>
                <mrow><mi>x</mi><mo>&NotEqual;</mo><mn>2</mn></mrow>
            </mtd>
        </mtr>
    </mtable>
</math>
```

[image: How Firefox renders three aligned equations with default styles]

**Problem:** the table content renders very small, especially in the `<mfrac>`.

**Solution:** That’s because `<mtable>` sets `math-style: compact;` by default. Use CSS to set `math-style: normal;` instead. (MathML Core is supposed to integrate better with CSS, so maths can be styled the same way as anything else on the Web.)

**Problem:** Nothing but Safari actually [supports `math-style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/math-style#browser_compatibility) as of this writing.

**Solution:** Bury your head in your hands and wait for a future browser release. At least Firefox has a config option to enable it, so I can show you how it *should* look.

[image: How Firefox renders three aligned equations with the math-style property set]

**Problem:** You want your equations to be left-aligned.

**Solution:** Again, CSS is the way to go… but MathML lacks an equivalent to `<col>`/`<colgroup>` for styling a whole table column at once. Work around it using selectors (and possibly classes) to target the relevant cells. In this case, I used `mtd:nth-child(3) { text-align: left; }`.

[image: How Firefox renders three aligned equations with some parts left-aligned]

**Problem:** There’s a big whack of spacing at the right side of the equations (the third column), and it’s not part of the cell padding nor of the space between cells.

**Solution:** ???

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<maligngroup/>`

Comment: Why would you want to malign the poor equations? They're convoluted enough already. Just kidding, how would you apply `maligngroup`?